# Максимальный элемент поменять местами с минимальным элементом

Tags: c#

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Введите N");
            int N = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("Pi = 3.14");
            const double Pi = 3.14;
            int[] Z = new int[N];

            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Введите Z[{0}]=", i);
                Z[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }

            double Sum = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
                Sum += Math.Sin(Z[i]) - Math.Cos(Z[i] * Z[i] * Z[i]) * Math.Sin((Z[i] * Z[i]) - 4.2) + 4.27;
            Console.WriteLine("Sum = {0:F0}", Sum);

            double Pr = 1;
            for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
                Pr *= Math.Sin(Z[i]) - Math.Cos(Z[i] * Z[i] * Z[i]) * Math.Sin((Z[i] * Z[i]) - 4.2) + 4.27;
            Console.WriteLine("Pr = {0:F0}", Pr);

            double F = Sum * Pr - Pi;
            Console.WriteLine("F = {0:F0}", F);

            Console.ReadKey();
         }
      }
   }
```

Comment: - Это что такое?

Comment: Каким образом относится ваш код к задаче? Давайте не вставлять в вопрос абы какой код, который вы нашли. Кстати, ваша задача настолько неуникальна, что даже на нашем сайте были решения, вы просто не захотели нажать кнопку "поиск"

Answer (score -1):

```
var min = int.MaxValue;
      var max = int.MinValue;
      int minIndex = 0, maxIndex = 0;
      for(var i = 0; i < Z.Length; i++) {
        if(min > Z[i]) {
          min = Z[i];
          minIndex = i;
        }

        if(max < Z[i]) {
          max = Z[i];
          maxIndex = i;
        }
      }

      Z[minIndex] = max;
      Z[maxIndex] = min;
```